# How can I customize Subtotals/grand totals in Matrix visual Power bi using measures DAX

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix visual containing organisation hierarchy as rows and some custom metrics as columns.the column contains values like 100%,0%,EX. I am facing an issue when adding up these values (using inbuilt power bi Total).The issue is like when there are say 15 entries with 13 - 100%'s ,1 - 0%, 1 - EX the total will be EX.It would be great if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

The expectation was 93% as when EX comes I want it to be removed from Numerator as well as the denominator. so the total is like 14/15 and that accounts for 93%

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7lOg.png)

Comment: Add your sample data and expected output.

Comment: the added image above, the EX (highlighted in yellow is incorrect I was expecting it to be 93 % because there are 16 rows with 1 - Ex and 1 - 0%, and 14 -100%